# Does Google Dart JavaScript converter support older browsers?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dart, browser-support

Does the Google Dart JavaScript converter support older browsers or is it only supporting modern browsers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [technical overview of its official site](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/technical-overview/) :

You will be able to run Dart code in several ways:

1.Translate Dart code to JavaScript that can run in any modern browser: Chrome, Safari 5+, and Firefox 4+ (more browser support coming shortly).

2.Execute Dart code directly in a VM on the server side

3.Use Dartboard to write, modify, and execute small Dart programs within any browser window

---

There is little chance that the Dart -> JavaScript compiler will support older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It's supported in no browsers currently. However code in dart can be compiled to JavaScript.

Comment: I think he meant that the JavaScript created from the converter support older browsers or not.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what I meant.